# Transition on button border-color is not applied

Tags: html, css

I am having issues applying a transition to a border color. I have tried almost every possible variation to get this to work.

### The HTML

```
<button class="calltoaction">Click me</button>
```

### The CSS

```
.calltoaction {
    border: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ececec;

    -webkit-transition: border-color 3ms;
    -moz-transition: border-color 3ms;
    -ms-transition: border-color 3ms;
    -o-transition: border-color 3ms;
    transition: border-color 3ms;
}

.calltoaction:hover {
    border-color: #000;
}
```

I have tried [Fiddling](http://jsfiddle.net/rsg4e/73/) around with it, but with no luck.

### What i have tried

- `transition: all 3ms;`
- Moving/adding the transitions to the `.calltoaction:hover`
- using the `border: 1px solid #333` syntax instead of the current.
- Surrounding the `button` with a `div`

This example is rather simple and should be working, any ideas as to why it doesn't?

Comment: Actually transition is being applied. Increase time duration of transition to see it. `3ms` is too short to notice it. Use `3s` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember the transition time is counted in milliseconds. You have set it to 3ms which is far too quick. Set it to 3000ms.